# How to select multiple dates in Filter in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, pivot-table

I have pivot table which contains all 365 days in a year (in Row labels). I need to choose some dates on filter but continuous dates. 
I will enter a date manaually on Sheet1 in cell A10. Then, the pivot filters must always select from January 1 to the date which i entered.

Sometimes if the date is not available means, then it must choose the previous available date. Then atlast it must select the two adjacent cell values for the date which i entered.I used the code below but not working.

The problem with inbulit Date fitler in pivot table is, it will work only for 1 year. So only i need VBA. Help me to update.

[image]

```
Sub selectdate()
Dim ws1, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim dat1 As Date
Dim Data As Variant

Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
dat1 = Sheet1.Range("A10").Value

Dim pi As PivotItem
ws2.PivotTables("MainTable").PivotFields("Date").ClearAllFilters
For Each pi In ws2.PivotTables("MainTable").PivotFields("Date").PivotItems
    If Not IsError(Application.Match(pi.Name, dat1, 0)) Then
            pi.Visible = True
        Else
            pi.Visible = False
        End If
    Next pi
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: As you said your dates would be continuous, you can try something like `ws2.PivotTables("MainTable").PivotFields("Date").PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlDateBetween, Value1:="1/1/2018", Value2:="1/24/2018"`

Comment: @arul I already said. it is not working for two different years. Check my image